# Matplotlib Quiver with Negative Directions

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot the vectors (3,2) and (4,-1) using `quiver` from `matplotlib`.  However, the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = (0, 0)
Y = (0, 0)
U = (3, 4)
V = (2, -1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.quiver( X, Y, U, V, angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1 )
ax.set_xlim( [ -5, 5 ] )
ax.set_ylim( [ -5, 5 ] )
plt.show()
```

generates the following plot:
[image: vectors]

The (4,-1) vector got plotted as (-4,-1), but the (3,2) vector is correct.  What's going on, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code on my system (Python 3.6.1 in Spyder 3.1.4 using matplotlib 2.0.2 in either the IPython 5.3.0 console or the Python console all  running on Windows 10 Creators Update) I do not get the graph you show. I get

[image]

which is what you are looking for, I believe. You may have a version of matplotlib or other software that has a bug. Try upgrading to the latest versions and try again.

Comment: Matplotlib v. 2.0.0 fixes it.  Thanks!